# Way to implement resetApp for React Native with wdio-cli/? - webdriverio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio-v5

Hellow there! I am using the wdio/cli so I created the wdio.conf.js with this command, then I start doing the test. But the issues is when have more than one test in a single or multiple test files.

In the test file I have something like this:

```
 beforeEach(async function() {
    $('~home').waitForDisplayed(81000, false);
  });
```

Where home tag is a tag in the first view when the app runs in first screen. And appear this error:

```
 element ("~home") still not displayed after 10000ms
```

So need to do kind of driver.resetApp()/ But dont know how to do it, what import do I need to do etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `resetApp`? You can't user `driver` as "main object" - Everything is under `browser` variable. Try this

```
//async
await browser.resetApp(); 

//sync
browser.resetApp();
```

Check [Appium doc](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/reset-app/) + wdio documentation.

Comment: Yes, thats true. Thanks Felix, I solved yesterday but that is right!